# error while saving to a file Error: EMFILE: too many open files

Tags: node.js, fs

I am writing a routine for code generation and write to a file but it is throwing an error

```
{ [Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'C:\\file.txt']
  errno: -4066,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\file.txt' }

for(var i = 0;i<100000;i++) {
    var a = randomString.generate({
        length: 6,
        capitalization: 'uppercase',
        charset:'alphanumeric',
        readable: true
    });
    console.log(a)
    fs.appendFile('C:/file.txt', a + "\r\n", function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
    });
}
```

How this error could be resolved and what is the efficient way to store it in a file. I have used graceful-fs and it works fine with it, but need to know with the core node.js fs module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your goal is to append 100K random strings to a file, you shouldn't be using `fs.appendFile()`. Instead, use a [writable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) for appending the random strings to a file:

```
var fs  = require('fs');
var out = fs.createWriteStream('C:/file.txt', { flags : 'a' });

for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  var a = randomString.generate({
      length: 6,
      capitalization: 'uppercase',
      charset:'alphanumeric',
      readable: true
  });
  console.log(a)
  out.write(a + '\r\n', 'utf-8');
}
out.end();
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer is totally fine. Just sharing another option: open the file once and write to it multiple times.

```
var fd = fs.openSync('C:/Work/temp/file.txt', 'w');
for(var i = 0;i<100000;i++) {
    var a = randomString.generate({
        length: 6,
        capitalization: 'uppercase',
        charset:'alphanumeric',
        readable: true
    });
    console.log(a)
    fs.write(fd, a + "\r\n", i * 8 /* offset */, 8 /* length */, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add additional bytes for the `\r\n` suffix :-)